# Where to start in editing a wordpress plugin?

Tags: wordpress

I am a newbie in wordpress and I was given the opportunity to edit a certain plugin which is MarketPress, but then I had hard times dealing with it since I'm new to this thing and I don't know where exactly to go, I would want to edit an included dynamic_sidebar but I can't the file on where to edit this. Please help me. :(

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure of your level of understanding so forgive me if this is over-simplistic.

The sidebar content is driven by widgets, which is controlled from the Widgets admin panel. The only thing about a sidebar that you should be able to edit by messing with its definition are the wrapping markup for the whole widget and for the title, along with the sidebars name and description. The last two only effect text that shows up in the admin Widgets panel.

However what I describe above is not found with the [`dynamic_sidebar()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/dynamic_sidebar) method, rather with the [`register_sidebar()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_sidebar) or [`register_sidebars()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_sidebars) methods. These 'define' the name and settings for a sidebar. The [`dynamic_sidebar()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/dynamic_sidebar) method is the used to implement the sidebar by passing it that sidebars name.

The sidebar is then populated with widgets via the admin Widgets panel.

Typically sidebars are registered from within the `functions.php` file of a theme, but if a plugin contains templates there no reason why it couldn't also have its own sidebars. As for where the `register_sidebar()` function is being used in your plugin specifically, I couldn't say. Just search through it using whatever IDE you like, or grep if your comfortable with it.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I was able to find the register_sidebar() method on functions.php and realized dynamic_sidebar()'s role was only to call what you had in register_sidebar(), am i right? I don't know if I was in luck but when you mentioned widgets I then checked my post data and found out that an action was being called everytime the event is triggered. Thanks to you I was able to successfully edited it. Cheers

Comment: Yes, thats correct. As I explained, dynamic_sidebars() implements the sidebar you defined with register_sidebars(), and widgets populate them with content.